# Is Name Required For QBO Customers and Vendors or Isn't It?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

The docs on IPP for the QBO Customer entity

[Online Docs for QBO](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0400_QuickBooks_Online/Customer)

indicate that Name is "Required". However, those same docs say  "...if the FullName is not specified, then GivenName, MiddleName, and FamilyName are concatenated and used for the value of this field." Does this mean that if we query for Customers we can always expect to find a non-null "Name" field, or does it mean that we might get a null "Name" but should use the concatenation mentioned in its stead? Same question for Vendors? Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: (Consider asking the Vendor. You've already paid for this sort of clarification :D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Norman,
The Name will always be populated. Either you specify the name OR you specify the Given and Family name and it populates the Name field with those values.

Try this example. Login to QuickBooks online, enter the first, middle and last, then the display name populates automatically.

Here is the XML example when I only enter First Name, Last Name

`<Name>Jazz, Hugo</Name>
 <WebSite/>
 <Email/>
 <GivenName>Hugo</GivenName>
 <MiddleName>J</MiddleName>
 <FamilyName>Jazz</FamilyName>`

regards,
Jarred

Comment: Got it, thanks, although I didn't realize that QBO concatenates in Family Name, Given Name format. :)